# split a single data frame into numerous data frames by sequential pairs

Tags: r, dataframe

this is my first post here. I'm stumped on a bit of data wrangling. After some data processing, I'm left with a single data frame that I want to break into multiple data frames by pairs of columns, and ultimately merge into a single data frame of IDs with associated proportional rankings.

Here is an example data frame:

```
dput(
varA<-c(1,3,4,2,5,NA,NA)
varA1<-c(.99,.95,.93,.89,.84,NA,NA)
varB<-c(5,2,1,3,4,NA,NA)
varB1<-c(.96,.93,.91,.85,.83,NA,NA)
varC<-c(3,4,1,5,2,6,7)
varC1<-c(.92,.91,.90,.82,.79,.72,.69)

df<-data.frame(varA,varA1,varB,varB1,varC,varC1))
```

Which has the following structure:

```
varA varA1 varB varB1 varC varC1
001  .99   005  .96   003  .92
003  .95   002  .93   004  .91
004  .93   001  .91   001  .90
002  .89   003  .85   005  .82
005  .84   004  .83   002  .79
NA   NA    NA   NA    006  .72
NA   NA    NA   NA    007  .69
```

Each pair of columns (e.g. varA & varA1) consists of an ID number (varA) and a proportional ranking (varA1). Columns are different lengths (though each of the two columns in an associated pair are of equal length). UPDATE: IDs are not repeated in columns, but not all IDs are included in each column.

Ultimately, I will want to have a single data frame with each row as an IDs and with proportional values represented in each column. Such as:

```
ID   varA1 varB1 varC1
001  .99   .91   .90
002  .89   .93   .79
003  .95   .85   .92
004  .93   .83   .91
005  .84   .96   .82
006  NA    NA    .72
007  NA    NA    .69
```

As far as I can tell, the obvious way to accomplish this is to split the data frame of IDs and proportions into numerous data frames, and then merge based on the common ID columns.

However, I cannot figure out how to split a data frame like this in an efficient manner.

What makes this tricky is that the order of the IDs--the ranking--is the important information. I was able to calculate the proportional value of each ranking (and store it in a list as outlined), but I'm stumped when it comes to transforming those pairs of ID and ranking in the list, into a format in which I can couple it with other data associated with each ID.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: I have a few questions about your data before I want to submit a full answer, but you can split up the dataframe using this `lapply(grep("var[[:upper:]]$",names(df), value = TRUE), function(x) df[c(x,paste0(x,1))])`.  As for the questions: 1) you say that some of the `var`s are different lengths, but data frames require them to be the same length, do you just have NAs for the missing data? 2) Do any of the IDs repeat them selves for a given `var`. 3) Do all the `var`s have all the IDs? Please update your example to illustrate any of these problems and how you want them handled.

Comment: @Hack-R I have added a reproducible example. Thank you.

Comment: @Barker I have adjusted the example, because (1) yes, I have NAs in the empty cells; (2) no, no IDs repeat themselves for a given `var`, as shown in the example; (3) no, not all `var`s have all IDs, as shown in the updated example.  Thank you!

Comment: a visit to every base r function... `vars <- paste0("var", c("A", "B", "C")) ; 
data.frame(id = seq_len(nrow(df)), lapply(vars, function(x) df[order(df[[x]]), grep(x, names(df))][-1]))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# rebind odd and even columns
bind_cols(df %>% select(matches('\\D$')) %>% gather(var, id),    # gather odd cols to long
          df %>% select(matches('\\d$')) %>% gather(var1, val)) %>%    # gather even cols
    select(-var) %>%    # drop duplicate var name
    drop_na(id) %>%     # drop rows with no ID
    spread(var1, val)   # spread to wide form

#>   id varA1 varB1 varC1
#> 1  1  0.99  0.91  0.90
#> 2  2  0.89  0.93  0.79
#> 3  3  0.95  0.85  0.92
#> 4  4  0.93  0.83  0.91
#> 5  5  0.84  0.96  0.82
#> 6  6    NA    NA  0.72
#> 7  7    NA    NA  0.69
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using `melt/dcast` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), use `melt` to reshape it to 'long' format (`melt` from `data.table` can take multiple `measure` `patterns`), and finally reshape it back to 'wide' format with `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)
nm <- names(df)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]

dcast(melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("[A-Z]$", "\\d+$"), 
  value.name = c("ID", "value"), na.rm = TRUE)[,
     Var := nm[variable]], ID~Var, value.var = "value")
#    ID varA varB varC
#1:  1 0.99 0.91 0.90
#2:  2 0.89 0.93 0.79
#3:  3 0.95 0.85 0.92
#4:  4 0.93 0.83 0.91
#5:  5 0.84 0.96 0.82
#6:  6   NA   NA 0.72
#7:  7   NA   NA 0.69
```

Answer (score 0):

Base `r` only.  The code I have below can be combined to run in a single line, but I am going to split them up to make it easier to understand what is happening.

Uses grep to find your `var` variables

```
varnames <- grep("var[[:upper:]]$",names(df), value = TRUE)
```

Indexes your data frame to get the variables into seperate elements of a list.  `na.omit` removes the empty rows.

```
varlist <- lapply(varnames, function(x) na.omit(df[c(x,paste0(x,1))]))
```

Merges all of the data frames into a single data frame

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 1, all = TRUE), varlist)
```

In one line

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 1, all = TRUE), 
       lapply(grep("var[[:upper:]]$",names(df), value = TRUE), 
              function(x) na.omit(df[c(x,paste0(x,1))])))
```